# find directory older than 3 days and zip all files in it

Tags: linux, unix, find, zip

Can i find any directories with a condition like older than 3 days

and zip them then delete the directories?

I have 2 solutions.

1. zip all directories in 1 zip under working directory

   I tried

   `zip -rm ${WORKDIR}/`date +%Y%m%d -d "${DAY_TO_ZIP} days ago"`.zip`find ${WORKDIR}  -daystart  -mtime +${DAY_TO_ZIP} -type d ! -name "*.zip"``

   this command will zip all files include non-directory file.
2. 1 directory 1 zip  same path with a directory

thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Execute bellow command to find all directory older than 3 days and zip all file

```
        # find / -mtime +3 -type d -exec zip -r zipfile.zip {} +
```

-mtime +3 means you are looking for a file modified 3 days ago.

-mtime -3 means less than 3 days.

-mtime 3 If you skip + or – it means exactly 3 days.

Finally If you delete all directory then execute bellow command

```
       # find / -mtime +3 -type d -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

find ./ -mtime +x -print -exec gzip {} ;